# submit event is not firing when editing a cell in ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a UI with a Save button on the top and with  Grid columns setted to cellEditOnFocus : true, when I'm editing a cell and I have to do a scroll to the top to click the Save button it doesn't get called. I have to do another click, I also observe that the Scroll of the page goes back to the position of the row I was editing.

If I don't have to scroll the Save function works on the first click.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: If I am picturing your UI correctly, I think this is more of a browser thing. I've seen this annoying behaviour on pages without a ui-grid. My solution was to move the Save button to not be above the top of the grid, but instead to its right. This meant only one click was needed.